# Cant send a business_card.png to abbyy with ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, abbyy

I am just tryout some new technologies and find out about  [abbyy gem](https://github.com/madwork/abbyy) I created a free account on http://ocrsdk.com/plans-and-pricing/

I am following the instruction on the gem

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  def abbyy
    client = Abbyy::Client.new
    client.process_business_card self.business_card, exportFormat: 'xml', imageSource: 'photo'
    # Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - https://appname-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/client/business_card/1/bizcard.jpg
    client.get_task_status
    client.get
  end
end
```

but I am getting a this error

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - https://appname-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/client/business_card/1/bizcard.jpg

I made sure that the directory I am uploading is public

here is a link to a demo app https://github.com/mzaragoza/abbyy

Comment: Let me know if you get this to work.

Comment: @AlbyMoore Looks like it was solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `require 'open-uri'` to the top of your file.

Then download the file, and only then give it to abby:

```
def abby
  require 'tempfile'
  card = Tempfile.new('business_card')
  card.binmode
  stream = open(self.business_card.url)
  card.write(stream.read)
  stream.close
  card.close
  client = Abbyy::Client.new
  client.process_business_card card.path, exportFormat: 'xml', imageSource: 'photo'
  client.get_task_status
  client.get
ensure
  # ensuring every handle is closed, and ignoring exceptions, which could arise if handles already closed
  # or haven't been opened
  stream.close rescue nil
  card.close rescue nil
  card.unlink rescue nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I am still getting the same error https://www.evernote.com/l/AP3lTXBfCl5CRaE6nkFzv1ox9EF9y3V0B5w

Comment: Please tell us, what is Client#business_card? Paperclip attachment or something?

Comment: its a carrier-wave image hosted on AWS S3

Comment: Thanks this is what it is. I appreciate all the help